# how to stop a loop before last iteration is run in R

Tags: r, loops

I am attempting to apply a threshold to a data set of RFID tag reads.  I want to keep all the reads that have a time difference between them greater than the specified threshold.  I have written a piece of code that will do this, but since it is comparing two rows of data, when it gets to the last iteration, it produces an error.  This is a problem, bc I want this loop embedded in another loop and the error breaks the entire process.  Here is what my data looks like.  This is only a small portion, but it represents the larger data set.

```
data.rfid.split
                  date        Tag
1  0013-05-21 16:37:14 04179381FE
2  0013-05-21 16:39:54 04179381FE
3  0013-05-21 16:39:56 04179381FE
4  0013-05-21 16:39:58 04179381FE
5  0013-05-21 16:40:00 04179381FE
6  0013-05-21 16:40:02 04179381FE
7  0013-05-21 16:40:04 04179381FE
8  0013-05-21 16:40:06 04179381FE
9  0013-05-21 16:40:08 04179381FE
10 0013-05-21 16:40:10 04179381FE
11 0013-05-21 16:40:12 04179381FE
12 0013-05-21 16:40:14 04179381FE
13 0013-05-21 16:40:16 04179381FE
14 0013-05-21 16:40:18 04179381FE
15 0013-05-21 16:40:20 04179381FE
16 0013-05-21 16:40:22 04179381FE
17 0013-05-21 16:40:24 04179381FE
18 0013-05-21 16:40:26 04179381FE
19 0013-05-21 16:40:28 04179381FE
20 0013-05-21 16:40:30 04179381FE
21 0013-05-21 16:40:32 04179381FE
22 0013-05-21 16:40:34 04179381FE
23 0013-05-21 16:41:26 04179381FE
24 0013-05-21 16:41:31 04179381FE

#this is the threshold I want to use as to filter out unwanted reads.
thresh <- 33
```

and here is my loop to apply the threshold:

```
for(k in 2:length(data.rfid.split[,1])){
repeat{
  diff <- difftime(data.rfid.split[k,1], data.rfid.split[k-1,1], units = "secs")
  if(diff<thresh) data.rfid.split<-data.rfid.split[-(k), ]      
  if(diff>=thresh) break

  }
}
```

as I said, it gives me the desired outcome:

```
                  date        Tag
1  0013-05-21 16:37:14 04179381FE
2  0013-05-21 16:39:54 04179381FE
19 0013-05-21 16:40:28 04179381FE
23 0013-05-21 16:41:26 04179381FE
```

but it also gives an error:
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

how can I use this loop an another similar one to get the desired outcome without an error so that this loop can be embedded in another loop?

Comment: use `trycatch` to catch the error and handle it properly

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you want to stop when `diff` becomes `NA`. I added some other minor improvements to your original script:

```
for (k in 2:nrow(data.rfid.split)) {
  repeat {
    diff <- difftime(data.rfid.split[k,1], data.rfid.split[k-1,1], units = "secs")
    if (is.na(diff)) break
    if (diff < thresh) data.rfid.split <- data.rfid.split[-k,]      
    else break
  }
}
data.rfid.split
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for `NA` using `is.na()`:

```
# (...)    
if(!is.na(diff) & diff<thresh) data.rfid.split<-data.rfid.split[-(k), ]      
if(diff>=thresh | is.na(diff)) break
# (...)
```